# Wordpress 3.0.3. How To Change Main Site

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

I have moved a WPMu site to a new host, and upgraded to WP 3.0.3. Things are going pretty easy, except the previous website had a different URL as the main website installation. Now that I have moved the install, I don't need the previous URL as the main site but need to make a new URl as the main site. Where do I go about changing this? I've changed the entire database by changing the previous URL to the new URL, and the wp-config is set up correctly with new URL and htaccess has no mention of it. I'm running out of places to look on where to change the URL.

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, there is the general settings (which I am guessing you changed first before all of this)...but if you used custom fields that tends to trip people up because that's INSIDE of your post/page content entries. ALSO...there's a chance to didn't move your entire media library (if it was large) so you are getting broken image links.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to change site URL in Wordpress

1. Replace new site url with old site url in exported database sql file (use Notepad++ for fast search and replace)
2. Change site url in `wp-config` file
3. Change database information (db name, host, username, password) in `wp-config` file
4. Change site url in `.htaccess` file